# Google Sign In with the OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, google-signin

I'm trying to do a normal registration with the OAuth 2.0, but the console gives out this error:
Everything is tested on the local server[[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3ud1.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/49qMj.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJGl6.png)

[Authorized JavaScript origins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCbiL.png)

Comment: Share code, not pictures of code and share the error you got.

Comment: the answer in this post may be helpful, (@Evert comment 
 ditto, share your code don't insert pics) 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38720878/google-plus-api-error-gapi-loaded-0